# How to Ensure Default Date Range Filter Applies in Embedded Looker Studio Report?

Tags: filtering, dashboard, looker-studio, date-range

I'm embedding a Looker Studio report into an HTML page and want it to display data for the last 7 days by default. While I have set up a default "Date Range" filter within Looker Studio, which works as expected within the platform, this default setting does not seem to apply when the report is embedded into my webpage. The report loads all data without any date filtering applied. I'm looking for a way to make the embedded report respect this default date range filter.

I configured the "Date Range" filter in my Looker Studio report to show data for the last 7 days by default and then embedded the report into my webpage using the provided embed link in an iframe. I expected the embedded report to display only the data from the last 7 days when a user first loads the page, reflecting the default filter setting I configured in Looker Studio.

However, the embedded report displays without applying the default date range filter, showing all available data instead. I tried checking the embed settings and ensuring the report was saved with the default filter applied, but the issue persists. I was expecting the embedded report to automatically apply the same default date range filter that works within Looker Studio itself.